# How can I control the permissions an app has if I am on a rooted android?

Tags: rooting, root-access, permissions

Some apps ask for a ridiculous amount of permissions. Android tends to be you accept all the permissions and use the app or you don't accept all and don't use the app. This is different from how IOS handles permissions. For IOS, you can selectively allow permissions like location, notifications, photos, bluetooth, camera, etc. How can I do this on android. I don't care if it breaks certain apps. Sometimes their is a descent app that just ask for an overwhelming amount of permissions.

Any ideas? Android 5.1.1! No custom ROM. Don't have xposed? But I can install it if I need too.

Comment: what version of android are you using? you can check your version by going to "Settings" > "About phone". the version number will be under the heading "Android version". also, since you're rooted, are you using a custom ROM or xposed framework, etc? if you're using a custom ROM, what's the name of it?

Comment: @particlewavedelta 5.1.1

Comment: srry, i edited my original comment. take a look above for a few more questions.

Comment: @particlewavedelta I have been trying to figure that out, from what I obtained. I don't have xposed framework and no custom rom. I have SuperUser though if that means anything

Comment: unfortunately, there's no fine-grained permission control in your case. google added this feature to android in 6.0.x marshmallow. however, if you were to flash a cyanogenmod-based custom rom or the xposed framework, you could gain permission controls that way. there may be an app on the Play Store that will do this, but i'm not sure. what device are you trying to get permissions control of?

Comment: @particlewavedelta I can get xposed framework installed. But which module would I need to install for complete control. Xposed seems to be tricky with a lots of different modules to pick from.

Comment: here's a few to try. some may not work with lollipop 5.1.1. it's a trial and error thing with xposed these days.

[Permission Master] (http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.droidmate.permaster)

[App Settings](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.mods.appsettings)

Comment: @particlewavedelta I found Xprivacy works for xposed. Thanks for leading me in the right direction. If you post it as an answer I will be happy to accept it, so others with similar questions in the future can see it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33259/discussion-between-particlewave-delta-and-james-smith).